# Should a blog article's timezone for 'posted' date/time be that of the author or the visitor?

Tags: blog, dates, timezone

When a visitor is reading a blog post, should the 'posted' date/time displayed at the top or bottom of the article be based on the author's timezone, or the visitor's timezone?

This question isn't specific to any blog platform/tool, but rather a best-practices type of question.

Comment: The time zone of the computer that runs the website.

Comment: As long as the timezone is displayed, I do not think it matter. The problem is that timestamps are too often forgotten at all and where there are here they have no timezone. It also depends on the content: for article long in the past, precise time may not be very relevant anymore, a date can be enough.

Comment: This site sidesteps the problem by using relative times.   Rather than saying "answered Dec 11, 2017 at 10:15 AM GMT" it says "answered 4 days ago".

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Not quite, even sites that display a relative date/time (days/weeks/months/etc. ago) often still display the actual date/time when you hover over it. So there's really no sidestepping it... ;-)